# When are onclick, onsubmit etc. in HTML evaluated? Trying to debug "X is not defined" errors

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form

```html
<form onsubmit="Calculator.calculate(event)">
```

Later in the HTML document, I have a normal (non async, non defer) script tag that imports the JS code which defines `Calculator` and assigns it to `window`.

This mostly works, but I noticed in my exception reports that I'm getting sporadic exceptions about Calculator not being defined in Safari.

Is it possible that some versions of Safari attempt to evaluate the `Calculator` constant in the `onsubmit` immediately, thereby throwing the undefined error?

(I'm aware that very slow browsers might not have loaded the JS file further down and this would also cause the errors)

**Edit** Given the constraints of what I've access to in this project, `addEventListener` is not an option.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: The script in the inline event handlers is evaluated at the time the event fires.

Answer (score -2):

It is not directly the problem, but you should not be using `on...` HTML attributes anyway. Instead, after the script that defines `Calculator`, include another script, that sets the event handler using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: I know this is the standard "best practices" way of doing things, but given the constraints of this project, that's not a realistic option.